# Migration of database records from MySQL to PostgreSql (from 1 application to a revamped application)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

I have a question which I could not find a solution on google and stackoverflow.

The situation is that I am building a new application(portal) which will replace the old portal. The old portal uses Mysql, which stores all the members' data. 
Now I have to migrate all these members data to the new portal which is using psql.

I searched everywhere and most tutorials are about converting a database from one database to another on the same application. But now I am trying to migrate just certain records from old application to a new application, and also changing the database from mysql to psql.

Does anyone has any resources or tutorials on how I can achieve this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is an extract-transform-load operation. You can use dedicated ETL tools like CoverETL, Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, etc for this. Or write scripts to do it.

Comment: how about using mysql_fdw, mapping and acceding mysql database directly from postgresql?